# Setting localStorage from popup window

Tags: javascript, popup, authorization, local-storage

I have a popup window that handles the authentication of a user. I want to set the user's organization_id in localStorage so that I have access to it. Here are the following steps I take with a failure result.

1. Click login. This triggers the popup
2. Enter email and password. The popup closes upon successful authentication.
3. Check the localStorage. No attribute exists for organization_id

Here are the following steps I take for a successful result.

1. Modify the code temporarily to prevent the closing of the popup window.
2. Click login. This triggers the popup.
3. Enter email and password. The popup stays up.
4. Check the localStorage and find that there is in fact a correctly set organization_id.
5. Revert the code so that the popup closes again.
6. Click login. Triggers the popup.
7. Enter email and password. The popup closes.
8. Check localStorage. There is now an organization_id.

I am doing hard resets and emptying the cache after all changes.

What could explain this odd behavior? Why did checking it in the popup cause it to work?

```
handleAuthentication () {
this.auth0.parseHash({hash: window.location.hash}, (err, authResult) => {
  if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
    this.setSession(authResult);
    window.opener.location.reload(true);
    window.close();
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (err) {
    router.replace('home')
    console.log(err)
    alert(`Error: ${err.error}. Check the console for further details.`)
  }
})
}

setSession (authResult) {
this.auth0.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, function(err, user) {
  localStorage.setItem('organization_id', user.organization_id);
});
// Set the time that the access token will expire at
let expiresAt = JSON.stringify(
  authResult.expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime()
)
localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken)
localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken)
localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt)
this.authNotifier.emit('authChange', { authenticated: true })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the window was closing before the function was complete. The solution was to set a timeout on the closing of the popup window, like below:

```
// Do some function call

setTimeout(()=>{
   window.close()
}, 1500);
```